# Match trailing part of filename after fixed pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

I have several files named in the following format:

> Friends.S05E01.Trailing-text-here.mkv 
>   Friends.S05E02.Trailing-text-here.mkv 
>  ... 
>   Friends.S05E24.Trailing-text-here.mkv

I want to remove the *".Trailing-text-here"* segment from the filename and leave it as follows:

> Friends.S05E01.mkv

I tried the following code (where I echo the resulting filename during testing):

```
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | % {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace '^(Friends.S05E\d{2})\.*', '$1'.mkv
    echo $newName
    #Rename-Item $_ $newName
}
```

But the results are opposite of what I am seeking; the above code returns:

> Trailing-text-here.mkv 
>   Trailing-text-here.mkv 
>  ... 
>   Trailing-text-here.mkv

Why does the `$1` group match the trailing part instead of what I have specified?  I am on Windows 10 Pro, using `PsVersion` 5.1.15063.674.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape the dot `.` character. Also, include a `$` to force capturing till the end of filename:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | % {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace '^(Friends.S05E\d{2}).*$', '$1.mkv'
    echo $newName
    #Rename-Item $_ $newName
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  The trick is not the pattern, but the single quotes around the entire second argument to the -replace flag (i.e. `'$1.mkv'`).  It turns out my version would have worked as well if I had the single quotes properly placed.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, I wrote something a while back to do exactly the same thing. It just uses the length of `$baseName` to chop the file name, hence the xx, then appends .mkv

```
$folder = '\\nas\media\TV\Friends\Season 5'

$baseName = 'Friends.S05Exx' # Make sure ends in S00E

$files = Get-ChildItem $folder

foreach ($file in $files)  
{

  $fileName = $file.Name  
  $baseNumber = $fileName.Substring(0, ($baseName.Length)) 
  $renamed = $folder + "\" + $baseNumber + '.mkv'

  Write-Host "Rename $filename to $renamed"

  Rename-Item -path ($folder + "\" + $filename) -newname $renamed

}
```